# weblogic server start is taking too much time

Tags: weblogic, weblogic-10.x

Weblogic server (10.3) is taking too much time from starting to running status. I see, below lines took time to execute. Any reason, why it took much time here?

Jul 14, 2023 9:09:52 AM com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener contextInitialized
INFO: Initializing Sun's JavaServer Faces implementation (1.2_03-b04-FCS) for context '/console'
Jul 14, 2023 9:09:52 AM com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener contextInitialized
INFO: Completed initializing Sun's JavaServer Faces implementation (1.2_03-b04-FCS) for context '/console'
*****  Metadata lookup failed, id  = AMERICA/LOS_ANGELES

09:46:22,115 INFO  TXT_LOG_FILE_ID ### Host Name

Comment: The first action to do is to take several thread dumps during the startup phase to see where time is spent.

Answer (score 0):

> Any reason, why it took much time here?

First you need to identify which component is taking more than expected. During startup til the server is up and running, a sequence of sub-systems (JMS, DS, LDAP, to name a few) are started and the apps are deployed. If some of those sub-systems/apps aren't responding, probably a timeout exception will be thrown, but most of the time, timeoutexceptions aren't sent to the stdout, making more difficult to understand which sub-system or apps is presenting problem. As a result, the server will take more than expected to be available.

In your sample, you are suggesting that instance takes at least 35 minutes to start up. In that case, take a thread dump every 5 minutes and then compare them to try to identify the problematic sub-system.

Example: Assuming that the PID of that process is 3899. Use `ps -fea | grep java` to identify the PID for this WLS instance.

```
    export PID=3899
    while true; 
    do 
    jstack $PID >> /tmp/${PID}-THREADDUMP.txt
    sleep 300
    done
```

Once that component is identified, the question is why it's not responding on time as expected. The next steps will depend on that particular component.